# c++ unless wrapper construct for flow control

Tags: c++, flow-control

I have a program part that works similar to the following:

```
X->updateA();
X->updateB();
X->updateC();
X->updateD();
```

Each function is supposed to return an integer indicating whether it ran successfully or not, say `int ret_val=0` if successful and `int ret_val=1` if not.

I am wondering if there exists any wrapper construct that processes each function consecutively as long as `ret_val == 0`. In my case it shall also call `X->updateD();` regardless of the value of `ret_val`.

Right now I have:

```
int ret_val = 0;
ret_val = X->updateA();
if (ret_val == 0) ret_val = X->updateB();
if (ret_val == 0) ret_val = X->updateC();
X->updateD();
```

Which I think is not really readable. What I'd prefer is something similar to the while-loop, although it would have to check for the condition after each function call. Something along the lines of this:

```
int ret_val = 0;
unless(ret_val != 0)
{
  ret_val = X->updateA();
  ret_val = X->updateB();
  ret_val = X->updateC();
}
X->updateD();
```

Is there any such construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use exceptions. Effectively they are an external control flow mechanism which means that you do not have to litter your regular code with error handling and manually propagate every error and check for errors on every call. With exceptions, your original code is perfectly valid as-is and the compiler generates code to check for errors and propagate them to the caller if one occurred.

Comment: Do not use exceptions for control flow. _Ever_.

Comment: (But do use them for this.)

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, they *are* a control flow mechanism, it's just best kept external

Comment: After rereading about exceptions I agree, the use of them is pretty much what should be used here. In fact, the `try() {...} catch() {...}` construct itself reads already very much like what I proposed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should store pointers to the functions you wish to invoke in a container, then iterate over the container. That way you can do whatever you like with the result, and it'll be the same for each function call, without having to repeat that logic *n* times.

Comment: @Puppy: Yes, or `std::function`. That is the conventional way to do `X` over _n_ function calls.

Comment: It's the "or `std::function`" part that's important. Also, it's only really conventional where X is very large or dynamic.

Comment: @Puppy: `std::function` is effectively a function pointer. I don't think it's constructive to quibble over that.

Comment: There's a large mile of difference between a function pointer and std::function. As in, a function pointer is the `new` and `delete` of the "Store a function" world.